# Is this the correct site/forum for reviewing logical proofs?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, solution-verification

Although Mathematics.SE meta seems like a better location to ask this, apparently I don't have enough points to post there so... Is this the correct site for posting logical proofs in hopes of getting feedback on any errors in the proofs?

Comment: Feel free to ask your questions. Someone who is familiar with this topic will take the time to answer you.

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by "posting logical proofs". In general, you will find this site more useful if you ask about *mathematical concepts* rather than asking "here is a proof, please verify it."  It turns out to be quite difficult to say much about a particular incorrect proof besides where it goes wrong, but much easier to talk about things that are correct.  And there is very little that can be said about a correct proof.

Comment: You wrote that: *"Mathematics.SE meta seems like a better location to ask this."* Meta is definitely not a place for questions asking for critique of your proof. You should read [What's meta](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) and also [this detailed answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/what-is-the-difference-between-mathematics-se-and-mathematics-meta/21613#21613).

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you asking whether meta.math.SE is a good place for asking questions about proofs? Or are you asking whether math.SE is a good place for asking questions about proofs? (The way it is phrased now seems a bit confusing. You wrote that "meta seems a better place to ask this". You wrote this before your post was migrated to meta. And it is not clear whether "this" refers to "this particular question" - which is now on meta - or whether "this" refers to "this type of questions".)

Comment: And I probably should have added links to some older related posts on meta, which might answer your question: [Best way of asking “check my proof” questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597) and [Questions that Ask to Verify Solution to Problem](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8424). So current policy is that such questions are allowed. I should also add that this policy might change in the future, see the related discussion [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20961).

Comment: It seems quite evident to me that the poster meant to ask whether *math.se* is a good place to ask such questions, but wanted to ask this question on *meta.math.se* and meant to say that he could not due to his lack of reputation/points.